# How can I send a user to user message in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I know this is not a code related problem. I need an advice on what service can I use to send a direct message to a particular user using Xamarin forms. I have been studying about Firebase CM and SignalR but I am not sure which one will be better and easier to implement as I am new to xamarin. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know this isn't really an answer, but I've struggled with the same things. I've looked at Firebase and SignalR as well.  I've got the same situation, and decided just to non real time messaging.  Send and load messages like an email interface

Comment: This also seems promising  https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/ipm-quickstart-csharp   uses twilio ip messaging

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for the reply and suggestion. I can use the non real time messaging but that will kill the purpose of the app service. I found (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHHLyeak46E) which I think I can start with.